# Is there a way through which I can control type of load balancer like round robin , least-connections etc using helm charts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, helm, load-balance

I am researching different types of `loadbalancing` methods available through kubernetes .I want to implement & see before deciding on one .I'm stuck at how to actually define `typeof-loadbalancer`.If it isn't possible through `helm`  can anyone suggest other options please .

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 2 possibble options.

One is to create a **LoadBalancer** type for each service you want to be exposed. In case you have just one service that's great. That's rarely the case of course :)

If you build your k8s cluster properly ( having Prometheus-Operator doing the monitoring for example ) most likely besides the business logic service/s, you would want to expose  internal cluster valuable services like Grafana.

That's why even if you have just 1 service, for future extension of such type of need the best would be to use an **Ingress** resource. It providees a way to expose multiple services through a single IP address —  HTTP level (network layer 7).

You could play with HTTP headers essentially and do some path/host routing.

You express the definition for your object and helm would do the installation. Another option is to use a tool like ArgoCD, basically sticking to GitOps policy.

A fundamnetal knowledge is to be aware that the Load Balancer/Ingress would forward the traffic to the service, not the pods. Services are abstracted entities by kube-proxy, by default kube-proxy uses a round-robin algorithm.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Regarding the definition, it follows the standart K8s scheme [ **apiVersion**, **kind**, **metadata**, **spec** fields]. Example would be an Ingress created from AWS-Ingress-Controller.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: management
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grafana.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: grafana
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
```